# Crop and move an image. Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, image, grid, css-position

I am struggling with putting the image in the right place and crop it on top and the bottom.
This is how it is supposed to look (hero-section):
https://www.behance.net/gallery/161732057/CozyMornings-online-store

The whole project is build on grid.

I need to have a circle image that is moved to the left, bigger than the container and cropped on top and on the bottom. Also, it should be responsive.

I was trying to put an image in the wrapper. Give this wrapper position relative and overflow hidden. It doesn't work.

```css
.hero-image-wrapper {
  border: 0.3rem solid #968273;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -25%;
  left: -10%;
}

.hero-image {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image-wrapper">
  <img class="hero-image" src="../images/pexels-ekaterina-bolovtsova-6976906-mobile.jpg">
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden should be used on the main container, hero-section.

```
.hero-section {
    grid-column: 1/13;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0% 10% 0% 0%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]